# CheckBox in React not firing

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have a component with a checkbox in it and for some reason it's not firing. When I say firing I mean it does not console log or print out in the DOM. Nothing. I have tried onClick/onChange. Then I thought maybe this specific checkbox has a problem. But in the whole app no checkbox is firing. So maybe I am doing something wrong. Yes I have tried ChatGPT and checked elsewhere. Nothing works. Also restarted dev server.

```
import { useState } from "react";

export default function ThemeSwitcher() {
    const [checked, setChecked] = useState(false);

    const handleChange = () => {
        setChecked((prevCheck) => !prevCheck);
    };

    console.log(checked);

    return (
        <div>
            <label className="theme-switcher" htmlFor="themeswitch">
                <div className="background"></div>
                <input
                    type="checkbox"
                    id="themeswitch"
                    defaultChecked={checked}
                    onClick={() => handleChange()}
                />

                <div className="switch" >
                    <img alt="theme switch to dark" className="moon" src="/moon.png"></img>
                    <img alt="theme switch to light" className="sun" src="/sun.png"></img>
                </div>
            </label>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: Are you attempting to 'fire' the `console.log` between the `handleChange` and `return`?

Comment: Change `defaultChecked` to `checked`

Comment: Sort of. I also moved the console log within the onClick. Doesn't work.

Comment: Try changing the `onClick={() => handleChange()}` to `onClick={handleChange}`

Comment: I’m willing to bet your input isn’t getting a click event because it’s hidden with CSS behind your background div. If you used an onChange (which you should be using anyway) event handler it would probably work because of your label’s htmlFor

Answer (score 1):

Several things going on.

You should use `checked` instead of defaultChecked if you want the input to be controlled by state (this is for clarity and correctness, but won’t really solve your immediate problem). It will solve the confusion, though, about why your checkbox appears to change state without your component re-rendering.

Also, you should be using `onChange` instead of `onClick`. The most likely problem is that you prevented your input from receiving an `onClick` due to CSS. `onChange` wouldn’t suffer from this problem.

Comment: There's a bunch of CSS. I do agree, but it works with VANILLA JS and an onchange eventlistener.

Comment: And I have tried both by the way

Comment: @ZayyanMasud then change onClick to onChange and you’re done, but you should really still change defaultChecked to checked, otherwise the state value doesn’t really make sense

Comment: I did a bit of digging. The checkbox works. It stops working whenever it is inside of the Navbar which is declared in the _document.js .I am using NextJS btw. Maybe that's the issue?

Comment: What do you mean “works”? Do you mean it toggles its checked state? Yes, that’s because you’re using defaultChecked instead of checked. If you change the prop to checked instead of defaultChecked, it won’t “work”

Answer (score -1):

If you want to log the updated value of a `useState` change, then you can call it inside of a `useEffect` callback.  
This is because, were you to call the `console.log` from inside the `handleChange` function, you would see the old value of the state, as `useState` doesn't execute the state update immediately. By using a `useEffect` callback, you can place the state in the dependency array and cause an updated value to be logged on every change to that state. Like this:

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';

export default function ThemeSwitcher() {
    const [checked, setChecked] = useState(false);

    const handleChange = () => {
        setChecked((prevCheck) => !prevCheck);
    };

    // logs the state of the checked state when it changes
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(checked);
    }, [checked]);

    // the rest of the code...

}
```

This would cause a value to be logged after every update to checked by the `handleChange` function.

Apologies if I have misunderstood your requirements.

Comment: I have tried this already. Doesn't work. :(

Comment: This isn’t true

Comment: Clarifying: this isn’t true refers to the fact you need to use a useEffect in order to run a console.log. The OP has place their console.log in the component body, it should work just fine as it is. The fact that it isn’t means the state isn’t updating at all, most likely because the input isn’t receiving an onClick

Comment: Thank you for the clarification - I should have written 'can', rather than 'must' and have changed it accordingly. Appreciate the feedback!